# How to update view in angularJS when an object is updated outside of the scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an object outside the AngularJS scope that looks something like:

```
obj = { isBig : true, name: "John" ... }
```

it has many parameters and it was created outside the angular scope and it updates outside of angularJS (for example - via ajax call that I make with jQuery).

inside my controller I write:

```
$scope.obj = obj;
```

**How do I create an event that listens to any of the object's changes and updates the view ? So the event is the objects's changes**

Specifically I have a parameter called `obj.isAjaxCallFailed = true/false` that I use in the view as `<div ng-show="obj.isAjaxCallFailed"></div>`

It's not working. I tried using `$on` and I can't figure out any way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$watch()` on `obj` to listen for changes (in your **controller**):

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
   return obj;
}, function(value) {
   if(value) {
      $scope.obj = obj;
   }
}, true);
```

At the place in your code where you create or update `obj`, you use `$rootScope.$apply()` to kickoff the watches:

```
function someCallbackOutsideAngular(data) {
   var $rootScope = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$rootScope');
   $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      obj.someKey = data.someValue;
   });
}
```

Note: `angular.injector(['ng'])` should probably set somewhere outside the callback (no need to execute it all the time).

Comment: 'ng' is the name of my controller? my ng-app? or it is a constant that is called 'ng'?

Comment: 'ng' is the module which contains $rootScope. So in this case, it's a constant. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.injector